# removing items from recyclerview error how can i resolve?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

```
class AdapterClass:RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.ViewHolder>() {
    var indixepersonas:MutableList<Modello> = ArrayList()
    lateinit var context:Context
  fun   constructor(person: MutableList<Modello>, context: Context)  {
        this.indixepersonas = person
        this.context = context
    }
   fun remove(position: Int){
       indixepersonas.removeAt(position)
       notifyItemRemoved(position)
       notifyDataSetChanged()
   }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder { //gonfia
        val layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return indixepersonas.size
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item=indixepersonas.get(position)
        holder.bind(item,context)

    }
    inner class ViewHolder(view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        val nonbre=view.findViewById(R.id.nonbre)as TextView
        val apellido=view.findViewById(R.id.apellido) as TextView
        var clikc=view.apply {

            setOnLongClickListener {
                getItemId()
                showContextMenu()

            }

        }
        fun bind(modelar:Modello ,context:Context){
            nonbre.text=modelar.nome
            apellido.text=modelar.cogonome
        }

    }
}
```

MainActivity :

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView
        val adapter: AdapterClass = AdapterClass()
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            getPersonas()
            settingRecycler()
            registerForContextMenu(mRecyclerView)
        }
    
        fun settingRecycler() {
            mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview) as RecyclerView
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
            mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            adapter.constructor(getPersonas(), this)
            mRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
    
        fun getPersonas(): MutableList<Modello> { //crea array
            var indixepersonas: MutableList<Modello> = ArrayList()
            indixepersonas.add(Modello("angelo", "ferretti"))
            indixepersonas.add(Modello("angio", "ferretti"))
            indixepersonas.add(Modello("ademaro", "ferretti"))
            return indixepersonas
        }
    
    
        override fun onCreateContextMenu(
            menu: ContextMenu?,
            v: View?,
            menuInfo: ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo?
        ) {
            var m = menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo)
        }
        override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.remover -> {
                    adapter.remove( item.itemId) }
            }
            return true }
    }
```

error :

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2131165321, Size: 3 ////// out of index?
>
> item.itemId does not give me the correct index? at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:503) at com.example.delatetext.AdapterClass.remove(AdapterClass.kt:19) at com.example.delatetext.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:50) at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3563) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:384) at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:219) at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java

Comment: 2131165321 is the menu item id from R file, not the index of your item in the list. you should add your item click listener in adapter class. the method getAdapterPosition in Holder class should help you to get the index of the long press item.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your index to be removed here in `adapter.remove(item.itemId)`, replace `item.itemId` with the index of the item you want to remove, becase this `item.itemId` returns an auto generated id of the menu item

Answer (score 0):

Your crash is occurring at the line `adapter.remove( item.itemId) }`.  The reason is that your adapter method takes in a position, but you are passing the internal id of a menu item.  Apples to oranges.  Since it appears you only have one menu item designated for removing, you need to have some way of knowing which data item should be removed.  Maybe that's the last item in the current list, or maybe it takes user input.  However you determine it, pass in the appropriate position to the adapter.

Note: Your adapter should also be revised in your `remove` method.  Currently it exposes the app to a `ConcurrentModificationException`. (Imagine if the person is scrolling the list at the time the remove method is called - the adapter may try to bind data that isn't there).  Here's an alternative approach:

```
fun remove(position: Int){
    val newList = ArrayList(indixepersonas).also { it.removeAt(position) }
    indixepersonas = newList
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}
```

Note that I also removed the `notifyDataSetChanged()` call since that is redundant with the `notifyItemRemoved` call.

Comment: i use ur fun remove but Do I have to change something in oncontexmenuitemselect? still the same error ::://// override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.remover -> {
                adapter.remove(  item.itemId) }
        }
        return true }
} ////// fun remove(position: Int){
        val newList = ArrayList(indixepersonas).also { it.removeAt(position) }
        indixepersonas = newList
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }

Comment: Yes - as I said, in your onContextItemSelected method you need a way to identify the position of the item being removed.  `item.itemId` is not a position.

Comment: i try with     when ( item.itemId) {
            R.id.remover -> {

               
                    var nomeposition=adapter.indixepersonas.indices.elementAt(info.position)
                    adapter.remove(nomeposition)
                

            }  and nothing ;(